# How does Unity implement its RotateAround function to avoid jitter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, rotation

I have a GameObject that I am rotating around a given point in 2D using my own implementation which is the following:

```
public override IEnumerator transformPlayer(MyTransform target, GameObject selection)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    Vector3 around = SelectionScript.Selection.transform.position;
    Vector3 to = target.Position - around;
    Vector3 from = gg.Player.Position - around;
    Quaternion oRot = gg.Player.Rotation;
    int totalDeg = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Acos(Vector2.Dot(((Vector2)to).normalized, ((Vector2)from).normalized))) / Mathf.PI * 180);
    float total = totalDeg / 180.0f * Mathf.PI;
    int mul = GraphicsCore.IsLeftTo(to, from, Vector3.forward) ? 1 : -1;
    float angle = 0;
    float v = 0;
    // float prev = 0;

    do
    {
        
        angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(angle, total, ref v, 0.33f);
        Quaternion absRot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle / Mathf.PI * 180 * mul, Vector3.forward);
        gg.Player.Rotation = oRot * absRot;
        gg.Player.Position = absRot * from + around;
        // gg.Player.transform.RotateAround(around, Vector3.forward, (angle - prev) * mul / Mathf.PI * 180);
        // prev = angle;
        yield return null;
    } while ((total - angle) > 0.01f);

    gg.Player.Position = target.Position;
    gg.Player.Rotation = target.Rotation;
}
```

If you do not pay close attention to the animation, it actually gives a perfect rotation. But if you do pay close attention, you can tell that while the game object is rotating it makes tiny little shaking in random directions. It is more noticeable during the end of the smooth damp animation, which is much slower.

I tried out different things to eliminate the jitter: I looked at whether it makes a difference if I made little angle rotations relative to the previous rotation state (if you look at my code, it generates the next rotation state based on the original state). I also tried using `Quaternion.Slerp`. None of these solved the problem.

However, when I rewrote my code to use the built-in `Transform.RotateAround(point, axis, angle)` function, I experienced ZERO jitter/shaking. This is the rewritten code:

```
public override IEnumerator transformPlayer(MyTransform target, GameObject selection)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    Vector3 around = SelectionScript.Selection.transform.position;
    Vector3 to = target.Position - around;
    Vector3 from = gg.Player.Position - around;
    // Quaternion oRot = gg.Player.Rotation;
    int totalDeg = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Acos(Vector2.Dot(((Vector2)to).normalized, ((Vector2)from).normalized))) / Mathf.PI * 180);
    float total = totalDeg / 180.0f * Mathf.PI;
    int mul = GraphicsCore.IsLeftTo(to, from, Vector3.forward) ? 1 : -1;
    float angle = 0;
    float v = 0;
    float prev = 0;

    do
    {
        
        angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(angle, total, ref v, 0.33f);
        // Quaternion absRot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle / Mathf.PI * 180 * mul, Vector3.forward);
        /*gg.Player.Rotation = oRot * absRot;
        // gg.Player.Position = absRot * from + around;*/
        gg.Player.transform.RotateAround(around, Vector3.forward, (angle - prev) * mul / Mathf.PI * 180);
        prev = angle;
        yield return null;
    } while ((total - angle) > 0.01f);

    gg.Player.Position = target.Position;
    gg.Player.Rotation = target.Rotation;
}
```

I can not figure out what could this function could be doing different so that it is able to eliminate this jitter completely. Is my original implementation wrong?

Comment: As a complete alternative have you tried using `Vector3.Slerp`? Why exactly do you need this to be your own implementation? What speaks against using the built-in working solution? ;)

Comment: @derHugo No problem using the builtin implementation, it is just my curiosity. I assume the builtin function must be doing something extra, since my solution seems correct mathematically speaking, yet it feels LESS smooth than the built in version.

Comment: that's most probably not it but why do you round the `totalDeg`?

Comment: @derHugo in the game, the gameobjects can be rotated only by whole multiples of 60 degrees.